# No errors but some wanings in Xorg.0.log file,However X still black screen! Help please,ATI driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, graphics, xorg

My desktop is ASUS A43 with AMD Radeon HD 6730M Graphics.Recently I installed the Ubuntu12.04 system and I find that my cpu has a high tempreture since booted.So I realized there must be some wrong with my Graphics.

I had tryed every method to install the fglrx,such as install the lastest official Catalyst driver and the open source Catalyst driver but it always return me a black screen.

Now there is no errors in Xorg.0.log file,and I don't know how to solve.If you have some suggestions or methods,thanks very much.

---

My xorg.conf file is:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

---

And my Xorg.0.log file is :

[Xorg.0.log](http://www.hebicpa.org.cn/icpa/JS/Xorg.0.log.txt)